# How to set and reference date range in Python and then apply to a query?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, spyder

This is what im trying to do in Spyder

```
from datetime import datetime, date
start_date = date(year=2022, month=8, day=9)
end_date = date(year=2022, month=9, day=16)

start_date_str = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date_str = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

test_query = """
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(advertising_id)) FROM dataset
WHERE group_assignment = "TEST" AND day BETWEEN "{start_date}" AND "{end_date}"
"""
```

I get the error Could not cast literal "{start_date}" to type DATE at [3:49]
How do I just reference code in python within my queries? It seems so hard to find the answer

I need to set a fixed date in python so I dont have to change the date of every query im pulling using bigquery within python

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT advertising_id)` to make code clearer.

Comment: The code block you’ve shared has no `f` in front of the string defining `test_query`. The error you shared also suggest that you aren’t actually inserting the dates into your query. Otherwise code looks correct to me (once you’ve removed the extra parentheses jarlh mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

# Set the start date to January 1st, 2020
start_date = datetime(2020, 1, 1)

# Set the end date to December 31st, 2020
end_date = datetime(2020, 12, 31)
```

More infos [here](https://blogatmioari.blogspot.com/2023/01/how-to-set-and-reference-date-range-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments has correctly pointed out, the block of code requires an `f` to be an f-string (short for formatted string literals).

That's all.

So the code looks like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
start_date = date(year=2022, month=8, day=9)
end_date = date(year=2022, month=9, day=16)

start_date_str = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date_str = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

test_query = f"""
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(advertising_id)) FROM dataset
WHERE group_assignment = "TEST" AND day BETWEEN "{start_date}" AND "{end_date}"
"""

print(test_query)
```

And the result is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(advertising_id)) FROM dataset
WHERE group_assignment = "TEST" AND day BETWEEN "2022-08-09" AND "2022-09-16"
```